# Why HTML link did not look like a bootstrap Cancel button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I needed a HTML link but need it to look like a bootstrap cancel button.
So I wrote this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Login", new {@class = "btn btn-secondary"})
```

but did not work! It does NOT look like a button at all. It is just a link.
How should I fix this?

Comment: Your adding a route value, not html attributes (look at the html your generating) - use `@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Login", null, new {@class = "btn btn-secondary"})`

Comment: @StephenMuecke oh I see.. thanks.. post it as answer. works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong overload of `ActionLink()` and adding a route value, not html attributes (look at the html you're generating). Use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Login", null, new {@class = "btn btn-secondary"})
```